# How to get the correct results calculating two unix timestamps

Tags: php

I know this has been asked several times before but I can't seem to find the right answer. I want to calculate the difference between two unix timestamps and show this difference in days. I'm not concerned about minutes or seconds here.

```
$time =  172800 - time() + 1265010604;
echo floor($time/86400);
```

Where 1265010604 is the timestamp for today and 172800 is a 3 day offset. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't hurt to rewrite the magic number `86400` as `(24*60*60)` to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$now = time();
$then = time() - 172800;
$difference = $now - $then;
echo "It was ".floor($difference / 86400)." days ago";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to calculate the difference between two unix timestamps
>   and show this difference in days

This sentence captures your requirements and suggests a straightforward approach:

```
$difference = abs($t0 - $t1);
$days = floor($difference / 86400);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* First second of the day */
function dayStart ($date) {
    return mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $date), date('j', $date), date('Y', $date));
}

/* Get count of days between dates */
function daysBetween ($dateStart, $dateEnd) {
    return round((dayStart($dateEnd) - dayStart($dateStart)) / (24 * 60 * 60));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sonny. Cool function!

Comment: I made myself a class with static functions for doing all sorts of date calculations like this.